# Temerature gauge goes to zero

Tags: troubleshooting, gauges, temperature

Temperature gauge goes to zero when the engine is started. Very warm air comes from vents. AC nor heater are on. Outside temperature is 80. Is it safe to drive three miles to dealer?

Answer (score 2):

Check your radiator overflow to ensure the coolant is where it should be (between the high and low marks). As long as it's good there, you should be just fine to drive it to the dealer. Ensure you start from a cold car and drive immediately. I would bet there is not going to be an issue anyway, but by driving there directly with as little stop/go as possible, you're vehicle probably won't even be fully warm by the time you get there. This is the *just in case* scenario so as not to cause your vehicle any problems. Keep an eye and a nose out for different smells. I don't think it will be an issue though.